# Simple algebraic expression with the Levi-Civita symbol

Tags: tensors

I have a doubt about a simple algebraic expression with the symbol of Levi-Civita.

If $G_{\mu\nu}$ is an antisymmetric tensor I am almost convinced that the following expression is null:
$$ \epsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}\partial_\mu\partial_\nu G_{\rho\sigma} = 0 $$
because the differential operators are symmetric in indices $\mu$ and $\nu$. Can you confirm too? and is there a formal way to prove it?

Answer (score 0):

Because the indices of $\epsilon$ are antisymmetric, exchange $\mu$ with $\nu$ and $\rho$ with $\sigma$ and we get a $(-1)^2$. Then relabel dummy indices in the same fashion. Now the derivatives commute so we can exchange them, and similarly switching the $\sigma$ and $\rho$ on $G$ will give a $-1$.

$$\epsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}\partial_\mu\partial_\nu G_{\rho\sigma} = \epsilon^{\nu\mu\sigma\rho}\partial_\mu\partial_\nu G_{\rho\sigma} = \epsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}\partial_\nu\partial_\mu G_{\sigma\rho} = -\epsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}\partial_\mu\partial_\nu G_{\rho\sigma}$$

This shows that it's equal to itself but negative, which means it must be $0$.